# Is the platform required to compile and build Android apk

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have set up a Concourse CI pipeline to run tests and build my apk. I've built a docker image for my job to run in. The image contains the sdk tools, build tools and platform tools but does not contain the platform that corresponds to the compileSdkVersion. It seems to work and build the apk correctly, I can run the apk on a device. I'm slightly confused by this as I would have thought that the platform would be required. Does anybody know how this is working under the hood and what the minimum set of files are required to compile and build the apk?

Thanks

Comment: The SDK is required. What do you mean by "platform"?

Comment: @cricket_007 the "SDK" comprises of the various tools and the platform i.e. platform 25 which corresponds to android 7.1. You don't need all of it to compile and and build an apk.

Comment: I'm under the impression that you do. You can't compile java 8 code without jdk1.8

Comment: @cricket_007 as per my question, I don't think this is the case as I am able to run unit tests and build an apk with just the build, sdk and platform tools without the actual platform.

Comment: I'm not looking at the SDK Manager at the moment, please [edit] your question to include in more detail what you have installed. I know you at least need an API/SDK version, build tools, platform tools, and the Google repositories (if using those libraries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that gradle actually pulls down the platform during the build, I noticed it in the logs.